# Force bootstrap nav to mobile view on portrait ipad

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I currently have a bootstrap nav that will show the mobile nav hamburger at 768px, but the links don't display in a vertical list until 767px. I need to have the nav display the links the same on mobile portrait and ipad portrait.

CSS:

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
}

.icon-bar {
  background-color: #000;
}

.margin-top-ten-px {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.margin-bottom-ten-px {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.full-width-button {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}


/*  ----------------------  NAVBAR RENDERING  ---------------------- */

.login-dropdown {
  width: 220px;
  border-top: solid 5px #6cbc42;
  border-left: solid 1px #6cbc42;
  border-right: solid 1px #6cbc42;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #6cbc42;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.two-column-navbar {
  width: 50em;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4px 8px;
  float: right;
  border-top: solid 5px #6cbc42;
  border-left: solid 1px #6cbc42;
  border-right: solid 1px #6cbc42;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #6cbc42;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.three-column-navbar {
  width: 46em;
  height: auto;
  margin: 4px 8px;
  float: right;
}

.search {
  @include breakpoint(smmax) {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  .nav>li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
  .navbar {
    height: 121px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 9%;
  }
  .navbar-right {
    margin-right: 20%!important;
    margin-top: -167px!important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-header .collapse,
  .navbar-toggle {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .navbar-header {
    float: none;
  }
  #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 {
    background-color: #eee;
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand active" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
      </div>
  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left search" role="search">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">ABOUT US<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu row col-lg-3 one-column-navbar" role="menu">
              <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Responsive Column 1</strong> - This is the left column and the information should be contained in this column! </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu row col-lg-12 three-column-navbar" role="menu">
              <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Responsive Column 1</strong> - This is the left column and the information should be contained in this column! </div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Responsive Column 2</strong> - This is the center column and the information should be contained in this column!</div>
              <div class="col-md-4"><strong>Responsive Column 2</strong> - This is the center column and the information should be contained in this column!</div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">OUR RESULTS<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu row col-lg-12 one-column-navbar" role="menu">
              <div class="col-md-12"><strong>Responsive Column 1</strong> - This is the left column and the information should be contained in this column! </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">NEWS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">LOCATIONS</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">CONTACT</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/f2rhjg0u/4/**

Answer (score 2):

Max-width media queries should always be 1px less than the breakpoint. Examples:

```
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){}
@media only screen and (max-width:991px){}
@media only screen and (max-width:1199px){}
```

To change vertical stacking, use this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
        .nav>li {
            position:relative;
            display:block;
            float:none;
        }
    }
```

Comment: For an iPad mini, the portrait width is 980px. This adjustment works for the mobile nav toggle, but which class is needed to make the links display vertically and not horizontally?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is what you want.
 `.nav>li {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  float:none;
 }`

Comment: I've updated the code and fiddle in my question, but still not able to get the subnav to show at 992px and below, the same it does on mobile.

Comment: I can't seem to get the nav shown on iPad like in a mobile. I don't want the desktop version on iPad.